# Django Polling App gives an error of "No Polls are Available"

Tags: python, django

I did a search on all past answers but unable to get a clue.

In the Django Polling App tutorial, I have reached generic views. After defining views.py, urls.py and the templates (index.html, detail.htmls and results.html) when i go to the url localhost:8000/polls/ I get the message no polls are available. If I go to the url localhost:8000/polls/1/ I can see the "What's New?" question with choices.

My files below :
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Question, Choice
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now().date())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save() 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if latest_questions_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for question in latest_questions_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You made a typo: it is `latest_question_list`, not `latest_questions_list`, since that is the `context_object_name`.

Answer (score 0):

In your template there is a typo, change `latest_questions_list` to `latest_question_list`:

```
{% if latest_questions_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_questions_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
```

change it to:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Should resolve you problem.

Comment: The error is also located in the `{% if ... %}` statement. Normally however questions where the problem is a typo are closed, since it is unlikely to help other users: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/67579

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent an entire afternoon - sounds really stupid now !!! Yes the question can be closed.